# Refreshing OKTA Access Tokens from background

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-5, okta, refresh-token

I have .NET 5.0 Blazor server app and openiD OKTA has been integrated. Our access token will be expired in 1 hour and need to refresh it after that. I am using a cookie in UI along with accesstoken in back-end. What I am currently doing for access token refresh is that after 1 hour, routing to a controller action to refresh the token manually as below.

As I mentioned, I use a cookie and I validate the token inside CookieAuthenticationEvent which fires each time. Below is the middleware part configuration.

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, displayName: 

    "epd_local",
                   options =>
                   {
    
                       options.Cookie.Name = "epd_local";
                       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
                       options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                       options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    
    
                       options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                       {
                           // this event is fired everytime the cookie has been validated by the cookie middleware,
                           // so basically during every authenticated request
                           // the decryption of the cookie has already happened so we have access to the user claims
                           // and cookie properties - expiration, etc..
                           OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                           {

                          //HERE VALIDATING TOKEN
```

After above validation, if fails, route to below endpoint.

```
public IActionResult Refresh([FromQuery] string returnUrl)
        {
            var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = <<new time>>,
                RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? GlobalVariables.OktaCallBackURI // Url.Content("~")
            };

            return Challenge(authProps);
        }
```

The issue here is that this approach will refresh the screen and will lose the entries added at that time. Is there any better ways to refresh the access token in background without impacting the screen? I am getting a refresh token as well along with the access token after authentication, but not sure how that will be helpful here?

Comment: I am facing this problem as well. I tried putting token validation in the middleware but apparently once the Blazor server web is fully loaded, the behavior is as same as Blazor client-app; meaning any page will be loaded locally instead of going thru the request-response path that usual middleware does. In order to make it goes thru middleware, the web must be reloaded again. So instead, I put token validation in particular page's OnInitializedAsync and every time a user wants to access secured API endpoints. If you have discovered better methods, let me know.

Comment: I am using cookie and so validating token inside event "CookieAuthenticationEvents" as you can see in my shared code above

Answer (score 1):

I refined the implementation through registering OpenId events inside startup class. Inside eventhandler OnTokenValidated, the main property to set is **context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true**. The token automatically refreshes after this property set and no manual routing needed.

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    // this makes signout working
    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut,
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
    OnRemoteSignOut = context =>
{

    context.Response.Redirect("GlobalVariables.OktaCallBackURI +/logout");
    context.HandleResponse();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
},
    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
    {

    
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    },
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {

        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnAccessDenied = context =>
    {

        
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
                    
        try
        {
            if (context is not null && context.Principal is not null && context.Principal.Identity is not null)
            {
                var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                List<Claim> addToken = new();
                if (context?.TokenEndpointResponse is not null && context?.TokenEndpointResponse?.AccessToken is not null)
                {
                    addToken.Add(new Claim("access_token", context?.TokenEndpointResponse?.AccessToken));
                }
                if (context?.TokenEndpointResponse is not null && context?.TokenEndpointResponse?.RefreshToken is not null)
                {
                    addToken.Add(new Claim("refresh_token", context?.TokenEndpointResponse?.RefreshToken));
                }

                if (addToken.Count > 0)
                {
                    identity.AddClaims(addToken);
                }
                // so that we don't issue a session cookie but one with a fixed expiration
                context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;

                // align expiration of the cookie with expiration of the
            
                var accessToken = new JwtSecurityToken(context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
                
            }
            else
            {
                //hk todo 
                //redirect
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnTicketReceived = context =>
    {
        // If your authentication logic is based on users then add your logic here
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },

    //HK save for later
    OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("~/");
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnUserInformationReceived = context =>
    {
        //IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        RegisterUser(context);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
};
```